# Postgres query IN query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible in Postgres to determine if at least one result of query 1 is inside query 2 results?
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE
(SELECT id FROM users) IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_items WHERE item_id = 1)
```

I know that this query can be a nonsense, I'm just asking how to do that check in the where clause. In my real query (more complex), I'm getting:

> (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 21000 (cardinality_violation): more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

if there is more than one result from query1 (query1 IN query2)

**EDIT**

```
 select user_id 
 from notification_token n 
   join notification_folder f on n.user_id = f.user_id
where ((SELECT tag_id FROM notification_folder_tag WHERE notification_folder_id = f.id) IN (SELECT tag_id FROM event_tag WHERE event_id = 1))
```

tables:

**notification_token**

```
| user_id | notification_token                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | token1                               |
| 2       | token2                               |
| 3       | token3                               |
```

**notification_folder**

```
| user_id                | data                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                      | "useless string"      |
```

**notification_folder_tag**

```
| notification_folder_id | tag_id                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                      | 1                     |
| 1                      | 2                     |
| 2                      | 5                     |
```

**event_tag**

```
| event_id               | tag_id                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1                      | 1                     |
| 2                      | 2                     |
| 3                      | 8                     |
```

The result that I want is user_id 1 from notification_token.

"Where" should be true because at least one tag_id from the left side of the IN (result 1,2) is contained in the right side of the IN (result 1).
Anyways i get error when the left side of the IN is composed by more than one entry. It works properly with just one entry

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: you need to join items with users on some common attribute, I assume

Comment: Updated my question with data and desired result

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want items anyone who ordered `item_1` has also ordered.  If this interpretation is correct, then here is one way to write the query:

```
select distinct i.*
from items i join
     user_items ui
     on ui.item_id = i.item_id
where ui.user_id in (select ui2.user_id
                     from user_items ui2
                     where ui2.item_id = 1
                    );
```

Comment: `from user_items ui2 join where ui2.item_id = 1` - I think there is something missing after `join`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT * FROM items 
 
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users) 
IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM user_items WHERE item_id = 1);

If this doesn't work, go for relational database queries.